# Bar plot with many values missing bars when exported/displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar plot with over 3000 bars. When I display it in RStudio, there are periodic gaps in the plot which should contain values. I also get the Warning message: "position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect". 
I verified that the values are there when I used x11() from the R dev page (Control Multiple Devices) and stretched the plot partially across 2 monitors.

I understand that it is a large data set and the bar plot is less descriptive at such a large size. I intend to use the stacked bar plot on a smaller scale as an sorted tally of mutations per gene and wanted a scalable version for large files.

Here's an idea of the data frame that goes into the stacked bar plot, colored according to Mutation:

```
Gene    Mutation    value
ABC     MUT1        1
ZYX     MUT1        1
DEF     MUT1        0
ABC     MUT2        1
ZYX     MUT2        0
DEF     MUT2        0
```

As a temporary fix, I have created two options for geom_bar(). The larger width produces a new warning: "position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals" but the output bar plot doesn't show gaps.

```
barplot<- ggplot(bar.df2, aes(x = Gene, y = value, fill = as.character(Mutation)))+
  # For input file with very many genes, use the following:
  #geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1.5) + 

  # For input file with <= 150 genes, use the following:
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +

  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = mutvec, values = colvec2)+ 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5), "lines")) +
  xlim(rev(levels(bar.df2$Gene))) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)

# This then goes into ggplotGrob() and grid.arrange 
# with a heatmap which is the main plot
```

Is there a better way for this stacked bar plot to display all its bars on a small scale?

Comment: A bar plot with 3000 bars? Seriously? You should rethink your choice of plot.

Comment: It summarizes a heat map which is in the same plot. For each colored tile in the heat map, I increment the corresponding bar. It works fine on a smaller scale such as 100 bars. For the full data set, that's when the problem occurs.

Comment: Roland's point is that a bar chart with that many bars probably isn't a very effective way to display that data, which should have been obvious when you needed to use 2 monitors to see enough detail to verify your problem.

Comment: I agree. On a small scale, the stacked bar plot is more descriptive and you can see the different proportions. By changing the width of the bars to 1.5, I eliminate the spaces in the output but receive another warning message: position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals. I will reserve the bar plot for smaller heat maps.

Comment: @frost_wander you will be more lucky to get an answer , if you 1- create a sample of your data 2- the code that you have tried 3- the plot that you have 4 - the final plot or at least mention in your current plot where you have a problem (using MSpaint or gimp,..)